# Swift - Is there a way to check if a variadic parameter is not used?

Tags: swift, function, variadic-functions

I would like to know if there is a way to check whether the variadic parameter "addComplex" is used or not. 
I guess I could make the parameter type optional and then check if it's nil or not, but then I always have to include an instance of the Complex class when I call the function. 
Can I somehow make it work with the variadic parameter or better use an optional type?

```
class Complex {
    var real: Float = 0.0
    var imaginary: Float = 0.0

    init(real: Float, imaginary: Float){
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary
    }

    //takes default parameters and a variadic parameters
    func incrementBy(addReal: Float = 0.0, addImanginary: Float = 0.0, addComplex: Complex...){
        self.real += addReal
        self.imaginary += addImanginary

        if (addComplex != nil){
            self.real += addComplex!.real
            self.imaginary += addComplex!.imaginary
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check:

```
if addComplex.isEmpty {
   // variadic parameter not used
}
```

Comment: yeah, that worked !! thx! except the lines inside the if statement show now an error that says that: ("Value of type Complex" has no member "real"). Am I accessing the global variable "real" and "imaginary" wrongly?

Comment: Well, the variable addComplex is not of type Complex, it is an array - [Complex]. So you need to check if the array is not empty and if it is not, you can access addComplex[0].real etc.